# Geometric sequence help, please! How to know if first term is $n=1$ or $n=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm requesting help writing the general (explicit) formula: A company bought a vehicle for $58,200$. At the end of each year the value will depreciate by $15\%$.
Is the power $n$ or $n-1$?  How does one know?  This is in a section where we are learning about the explicit formula of a geometric sequence. Some examples call the first term a sub $1$ and some call it a sub $0$. I wrote it both ways but got different answers when using the formula to predict the price after $5$ years.  Help!

Comment: $n=0$ should correspond to the initial state of the system, where no time has elapsed and there has been no depreciation. Check this matches the initial price. Then, after $5$ years, you would have $n=5$. It would be natural to assume that the problem considers the purchase of the vehicle to be at the initial time. You could alternatively have $n$/the depreciation start from a different numbering (maybe starting earlier if the vehicle was bought second hand), but that would not change the result. In any case, 5 years later will be $+5$ on whatever $n$ was.

Comment: @Jam For an arithmetic sequence, $~0, 0+x, 0 + 2x, \cdots ~$ seems reasonable to me.  For a geometric sequence, $~1, 1 \times x, 1 \times x^2, \cdots, 1 \times x^{n-1},~$ (at the beginning of the $~n$-th year) seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Re previous comment, for a geometric sequence, this means that at the end of the $~n$-th year, the value is $~x^n.$

Answer (score 2):

It is up to you to write the expression in a way that makes sense.  You can use the exponent "$n$" or "$(n+1)$" depending on how you set it up.  And, you can start counting from $0$ or from $1,$ as long as you know what you are trying to represent.  Personally, I prefer counting from $0,$ but most math books use formulas that count from $1.$

Anyway, I would say:

$a_n = 58200(1-0.15)^n$

In year $0$, that is today, your vehicle is worth its full purchase price.

At the end of the first year, it has lost $15\%$ of its value.  Or, it holds $85\%$ of its value.  And, each subsequent year loses more value.